# Why do I get 2 processes when doing one fork?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

When running the below code which uses [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) I get two sleep processes and not one as expected.

```
18748 pts/2    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
18749 pts/2    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
18750 pts/2    S+     0:00 sleep 12345
18751 pts/2    S+     0:00 sleep 12345
```

And also it doesn't execute the `print` commands until the `sleep` command exits. I would have expected that the perl script would continue when I fork. Or am I missing something?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(5);

my $pid = $pm->start;
system("sleep 12345");
print "pid inside $pid\n";
$pm->finish;

print "pid outside $pid\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you called `system` in the parent and in the child. Check `start`'s return value as documented.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);

my $pid = $pm->start;
if (!$pid) {
   print "From child: $$\n";
   system("sleep 12345");
   $pm->finish;
}

print "From parent: $$ $pid\n";
$pm->wait_all_children();
```

Of course, if you don't do anything between `system` and `finish`, you might as well use `exec` to get perl+sleep instead of perl+perl+sleep.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);

if (!$pm->start) {
   exec("sleep 12345")
      or die($!);
}

$pm->wait_all_children();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need =) What does this error mean `Cannot start another process while you are in the child process at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 463.` I get it when I run the script.

Comment: Changing to `system("sleep 3")` the script never exits.

Comment: Error introduced in cleanup. Fixed.